# How do I install Slax to a usb stick?

Tags: live-usb, bootable

I want to install Slax on my usb stick, but I just can't get it to work. I tried copying the contents of the .zip file to the usb stick, and I got to some grub rescue thingy. I also tried Unetbootin, but it couldn't download the iso itself, and when I downloaded the iso manually, it couldn't find the /slax files. How do I get it working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `dd`, like `dd if=/path/to/slax.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=1M` . Make sure to replace `sdb` with the actual USB stick.

Comment: what does the `bs=1M` mean?

Comment: This didn't work for me with slax-64bit-9.3.0.iso.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a windows PC you can try YUMI, which in my opinion is the best tool to make bootable usb, with multiboot option.

I regret to admit but YUMI works only to windows.

Comment: What about WINE?